# video 100% width and height 220px

Tags: html, css

I have a video, and I want it to FULL 100% of the width, and 220px of the height

```
<video  controls="controls">
   <source src="video/sport.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="video/sport.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
   <source src="video/sport.flv" type="video/flv" />
```

but the problem when i change the height to 220px also width change as well

```
video {
 width: 100% !important;
 height:220px !important;
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking this answer http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you literally gave it a width of 100% and a height of 220px your video would likely look very stretched, horizontally. A better idea is to contain the video in a container div that with overflow hidden set that has the dimensions you want. For example:

```
<div id="container">
  <video  controls="controls">
    <source src="video/sport.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="video/sport.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="video/sport.flv" type="video/flv" />
</div>

video{
  width: 100%;
}
#container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This way, the video will have a normal aspect ratio, but will have the correct width. Then, the containing div just hides whatever part of the video exceeds 220px in height.